# Refresh elements of GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new to GUIs in java.

For example, I need to update just 1 element (e.g., `JLabel`). In Tkinter I would use something like `root.update()` or `root.update_idletasks()`. I wonder if a similar simple function exists in for applications made with swing. I've tried `gui_element.SetVisible(false)` and `gui_element.SetVisible(true)` and similar stuff, but not very successfully. I suspect something with `javax.swing.Timer` should work, but do not know how.

**EDIT** Here is the code. Please let me know if you find other errors. Thanks

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class sof_sample{

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    private static JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Fractal Geometry");
    public static JButton quit_button = new JButton("Quit");
    private static JButton run_button = new JButton("Run");
    private static JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    public static JLabel label_iter = new JLabel(); 
    private static GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(2,20);
    private JOptionPane msg1 = new JOptionPane();
    private static int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AuxClass1 inst1 = new AuxClass1();
        quit_button.addActionListener(inst1);
        run_button.addActionListener(inst1);
        label1.setText("Iteration");
        label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label_iter.setText("0");
        label_iter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));      
        label_iter.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label_iter.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        //add widgets to the frame
        frame1.add(label1);
        frame1.add(label_iter);
        frame1.add(run_button);
        frame1.add(quit_button);

        frame1.setLayout(layout1);
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //frame1.pack();
        frame1.setSize(250, 75);
        frame1.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class AuxClass1 implements ActionListener{
    sof_sample inst2 = new sof_sample();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1){

        if (event1.getSource()==inst2.quit_button){
            System.exit(0);

        }
        else{
            for (int i=0;i<20000;i++){

                inst2.label_iter.setText(Integer.toString(i));

            }
            //msg1.showMessageDialog(frame1, "Not yet!");

        }


    }



}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swing is event driven. All components work through the MVC pattern. You don't need to explicitly repaint it by hiding/showing in order to update it's representation on the screen.

You just do `yourLabel.setText("your new text")` and the new text will appear on the label.

Keep in mind that most GUI-updates (the `setText` is an exception) needs to be performed on the EDT, so use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` etc if you're update is triggered by, say, a network message.

If you do structural changes to the GUI you'll have to `revalidate()`/`repaint()` though.

Comment: I tried `repaint()`. Nothing changed. If, say, there is an update of a counter, I use `label_name.setText(Integer.toString(i))` in the loop for i<100, but I only see the last value (99). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post an SSCCE and I'll have a look.

Comment: You're hogging the EDT (the threads that continuously redraws the GUI). Execute the loop in another thread to avoid preventing the EDT from doing its work (update the GUI).

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more specific please? I don't quite understaind what 'hog the edt' is.

Answer (score 0):

By using Javax.swing.Timer you can achieve your goal.

```
    timer = new Timer(100,new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            if(i==100){
                timer.stop();
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
```

When you want to change the values on JLabel, at that point just start the timer by using `timer.start()`, so the values on the label will be changed until 100. when the `i` value reaches 100, `timer.stop()` will stop the timer.

Here is the javax.swing.timer tutorial. Have a look at this.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Download the working example from below link...

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9U-BwYu62ZaQWZMWloxdHp0YWs

I think it works for you..